# Optimising queries in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, mongodb-java

I am working on optimising my queries in mongodb.

In normal sql query there is an order in which where clauses are applied. For e.g. `select * from employees where department="dept1" and floor=2 and sex="male"`, here first `department="dept1"` is applied, then `floor=2` is applied and lastly `sex="male"`.

I was wondering does it happen in a similar way in mongodb.
E.g.
`DbObject search = new BasicDbObject("department", "dept1").put("floor",2).put("sex", "male");`
here which match clause will be  applied first or infact does mongo work in this manner at all.

This question basically arises from my background with SQL databases.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no indexes we have to scan the full collection (**collection scan**) in order to find the required documents. In your case if you want to apply with order [department, floor and sex] you should create this compound index:

```
db.employees.createIndex( { "department": 1, "floor": 1, "sex" : 1 } )
```

As documentation: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/

> db.products.createIndex( { "item": 1, "stock": 1 } )
>
> The order of the fields in a compound index is very important. In the
>   previous example, the index will contain references to documents
>   sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of
>   the item field, sorted by values of the stock field.

Comment: does a compound index like `db.employees.createIndex( { "department": 1, "floor": 1, "sex" : 1 } )` help when i am querying with a subset of fields in the index like `{"department" : "dept"1, "floor" : 2}` or `{"floor" : 2}`

Comment: check and scroll down the reference in my answer https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes. In your case the index { "department": 1, "floor": 1, "sex" : 1 } will help you in queries as: (1) dep, (2) dep/floor and (3) dep/floor/sex. If you want to search by floor quickly u have to create another index

Comment: One more thing - assume there are no indexes, then which one the match clause will be applied first. Is there any rule for that ?

Comment: As I said: "If there are no indexes we have to scan the full collection (collection scan) in order to find the required documents." You can check the different approaches executing your query with explain() method: db.employees.createIndex( { "department": 1, "floor": 1, "sex" : 1 } ), create a compound index, as well as, single indexes for yours different fields, then drop compound index, while always checking the "winningPlan" in the explain result

Comment: better execute this query with projection: db.employees.createIndex( { "department": 1, "floor": 1, "sex" : 1 }, {_id: 0, department: 1, floor:1, sex:1} )